# R knitr - kable table html formatting for small text

Tags: html, r, fonts, html-table, knitr

I am trying to format a table in R markdown (compiling to HTML) using `knitr::kable` to be as small as possible. Perhaps by making the text smaller for example. However by googling around a lot I have figured out how to control these individual elements, but the table stays the same size. I thought it should get smaller as the elements required less space, but that did not happen.

So what else do I have to set to make the table smaller?

Here is the code:

````
---
title: "kable table formating"
output: html_document
---
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
  td{
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 4pt;
    padding:0px;
    cellpadding="0";
    cellspacing="0"
  }
  th {
    font-family: Arial; 
    font-size: 4pt;
    height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #ccccff;
  }
  table { 
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
--->
</STYLE>

```{r echo=T}
library(knitr,quietly=T)

n <- 14
m <- runif(n*n)
dim(m) = c(n,n)
df <- data.frame(m)
kable(df,padding=0)
```
````

And here is the output - obviously I don't need all that whitespace:

[image]

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319457/display-a-data-frame-as-table-in-r-markdown) help

Comment: @rawr, instead of a separate CSS file, he's included the CSS in his rmarkdown file.  I actually don't think it has anything to do with the padding, but with the width.  My guess is that `kable` is defaulting to a table width of 100% of the page width.  I'm not sure how to address that.

Comment: Nevermind.  yes I do.  You're missing the `format = "html"` argument.  You're not making an HTML table at all, but a markdown table, which doesn't recognize the padding argument.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like a html table to me :). I didn't realize there were different kinds of tables. So I suppose I have two options, work with an html table or an R-markdown table. I suppose the latter work on things like PDF, etc. too.

Comment: It's a tricky and subtle difference.  I almost didn't catch it, and I play with this kind of stuff a lot.

Comment: or use `htmlTable::htmlTable` instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You only need to add `format="html"` to your `kable` call and you'll have it.  By default, `kable` produces code for a markdown table (compare the results of `kable(df)` and `kable(df, format = "html")`

````
```{r echo=T}
library(knitr,quietly=T)

n <- 14
m <- runif(n*n)
dim(m) = c(n,n)
df <- data.frame(m)
kable(df, format = "html", pad=0)
```
````

Which gives you this:

[image]

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks a lot, don't see how I would have found that.

Comment: Added a display of the results so you can see how much better it is.